# When sharing a document through Google Drive, is all its revision history also shared?

Tags: google-drive, privacy, sharing, version-control

Imagine the following scenario:

- on **Day 1** I create a text document on Google Drive.
- on **Day 2** I edit it.
- on **Day 3** I share it with John so that "John can edit".

Can John see the version from Day 1 in the revision history, or should I create a new document and share this one if I want to hide the old versions from John?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, totally. These small example shows a document shared with me on june 2nd; and I'm able to see all the previous edits (the document was created on june 1st)

[image: The versions change view of the document]

Comment: Is there way to disable this when sharing a document with 'can comment' option enabled?